# How to create dynamic date range iteration in Talend?

Tags: rest, loops, talend

Ihave StartDate and EndDate stored in 2 globalmap variables:
globalMap.put("StartDate","2020-10-01")
globalMap.put("EndDate","2020-11-01")

I want to put in the daily iteration. I want to retrieve the single day of the set time frame and pass it into the path of the TRestClient component to retrieve a daily json.

> ((String)globalMap.get("StartDate"))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uue7K.png)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Okey if i understand ! you want to retrieve the day "StartDate"  so that in what you wrote  date would be 2020-09-31 . isn't it ? your exapmle is not clear . could you give more informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey i've written this code in a tjava to get the day -1  :

You have to declare a context variable named **StartDate**  who have type String .

```java
globalMap.put("StartDate","2020-10-01") ; 

context.StartDate =  TalendDate.addDate((String)globalMap.get("StartDate"), "yyyy-MM-dd", -1,"dd"); 

System.out.println("My Start Date -1  : "+ context.StartDate);
```

Your output would be

> [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3835
> [statistics] connected
> My Start Date -1  : 2020-09-30
> [statistics] disconnected

In your tRestClient you have just to call ***context.startDate***

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. I have partly solved my problem. This way my job works to extract daily data. I should also retrieve historical data,by inserting two variables I thought that by calculating the difference of the period (end date - start date) to iterate one day at a time and retrieve all the data automatically.
Or I was trying the following way in the tDBInput component I would retrieve the dates and pass them one at a time to the TrestClient component, but it doesn't work. Currently, all the dates come in at once
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vglbe.png)

Comment: could you give me an example and more details about how you want to retrieve you historical date , I could help  or try to open a new topic i will respond there .

Comment: Thank you very much. I have created this new request: [Link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938265/talend-flow-passing-one-date-at-a-time-in-trestclient)