# Talend flow: Passing one date at a time in TrestClient

Tags: mysql, loops, talend

From the attached image, I have a list of dates as output in the TDbInput component: SELECT distinct date_format(DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') as date FROM calendar.

I should pass as a variable one date at a time to the Trestclient component. How can I do this?

[job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT32K.png)

Comment: You have to use iterate other of onComponentOk and get your date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use tFixedFlowInput component and iterate the from tFlowToIterate.
This will iterate one entry at a time. Below is the snipping on the process.

[image]

Comment: @davidescolari, my pleasure. If you feel it correct can you please mark the answer as correct. Thank you